# ggplot formula for a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to get a bar graph of medals in R. I have 3 distinct columns (gold, silver, bronze). The columns for gold medals has a total of 8, the silver has 10, and the bronze has 13.
For the code, I started writing: ggplot(data, aes(x=?)) + geom_bar()
I am not sure how to write all 3 gold medals on the function where it shows x=?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like I can help out with this. Can you just post an example of you dataset using `dput(mydata)` or `dput(head(mydata))`

Comment: Not sure how to post dataset here!

Comment: Still not see it. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Try this link to dataset. 
https://olympics.com/tokyo-2020/olympic-games/en/results/all-sports/medal-standings.htm

Answer (score 0):

For plotting purposes, it is *"easier"* to work with long data instead of wide. Below I converted the data you mentioned in your comment to long and plotted the data as a grouped bar.

```
library(tidyverse)

# load data
raw_data <- structure(list(Rank = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                           `Team/Noc` = c("United States of America", "People's Republic of China", "Japan", "Great Britain", "ROC", "Australia"), 
                           Gold = c(39, 38, 27, 22, 20, 17), 
                           Silver = c(41,32, 14, 21, 28, 7), 
                           Bronze = c(33, 18, 17, 22, 23, 22), 
                           Total = c(113, 88, 58, 65, 71, 46), 
                           `Rank by Total` = c(1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6)), 
                      row.names = c(NA,-6L), 
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# convert wide data to long
long_data <- raw_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`Team/Noc`, names_to = 'Medal') %>% # convert wide data to long format
  filter(Medal %in% c("Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")) # only select medal columns

# plot
ggplot(long_data) +
  geom_col(aes(x = `Team/Noc`,
               y = value,
               fill = Medal),
           position = "dodge" # grouped bars
           )
```

[image]

Hope this gets you started!

Comment: Thanks David! It's just that at the beginning, there were 1080 medals handed out. I want to create a graph breaking down the 3 categories (gold, silver, bronze). After calculating the breakdown (sum(data$gold_medal)) and so forth, I got the exact number but I couldn't figure out how to it right on a ggplot formula.